# auditing all tables in a schema

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I was wondering if there is a way (in Oracle(11g)) to audit all of the tables in a given schema. I have a lot of tables that need to be audited and don't want to have to manually audit each individual tables. Would a cursor be appropriate in this situation? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Here is the simple cursor I thought might work..

```
cursor table_names is
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tables
  where owner like 'MYSCHEMA%';
  begin 

  for x in table_names
  loop 
  audit_all := 'audit all on table_name';

  end loop;

  end;
```

Comment: Why don't you try it with two tables and see how it works out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL to generate and execute the audit statements

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT owner, table_name
              FROM all_tables
             WHERE owner like 'MYSCHEMA%')
  LOOP
    l_sql_stmt := 'AUDIT ALL ON ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
```